# C Program stopped working after using scanf instead of var=0

Tags: c, vector, allocation

So I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int functie ( int v[], int nr, int z)
{
    int i,count;
    scanf("%d", &z);
    for(i=0;i<nr;i++) {
        if(z==v[i]) {
            count=count+1;
        }
    }
    return z;
}

int main()
{
    int i,nr,z;
    fscanf("%d", &z);
    FILE *f;
    FILE *g;
    f=fopen("data-in.txt", "r");
    fscanf(f,"%d",&nr);
    int *v=malloc(nr*sizeof(int));
    for(i=0;i<nr;i++) {
        fscanf(f,"%d",&v[i]);
    }
    g=fopen("data-out.txt", "w");
    fprintf(g,"%d %d", functie(v,nr,z));
    fclose(f);
    fclose(g);
    free(v);
}
```

and before I had int z=0; instead of trying to scanf my var z.
When I run this I get a stopped working error.

I have an array with numbers (integers) read from file, first line is the number of elements and second line the elements.
I need a var lets say z to check how many times an element appears in vector (check if scanned number z is equal to an element and +1 count )

example:

in file

4 (cuz I have 4 elements )

1 2 3 3 ( my elements )

than scan z as 3
z==3 true 
count=1
again
count=2

Comment: `fscanf` is taking more than 2 parameters.

Comment: MULTIPLE error. Uninitializes variables (`count` and others), wrong used fscanf. I guesss compiler give many warnings and You ignore it

Comment: enabling the warnings and reading them would allow to avoid most errors...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues here, both in `main`.  First:

```
fscanf("%d", &z);
```

This function expects a `FILE *` for the first argument, which you didn't specify.  Presumably you wanted to read from the console instead, so use `scanf`:

```
scanf("%d", &z);
```

Second issue:

```
fprintf(g,"%d %d", functie(v,nr,z));
```

Your format string is expecting two integer arguments, but you're only passing in one.  Get rid of the extra format specifier:

```
fprintf(g,"%d", functie(v,nr,z));
```

Comment: solved it, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

fscanf will not be delimited by newlines. Best thing to do is eat through file a line at a time with fgets. So, add a line buffer to the top of main:

```
char line[16];  // assuming integers will actually be small
```

After opening your file as above with 'f':

```
if (fgets(line, sizeof(line), f))
{
    int count = atoi(line);
    int *v = (int *) malloc(count * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < count && fgets(line, sizeof(line), f); ++i)
    {
        v[i] = atoi(line);
    }
}
```

You should absolutely add error checking to the above, which is minimal and for concept only (e.g. guard against bad input, buffer overflow, exceptions, count being wrong leaving you uninitialized integers at the end of the array, etc.) as this will only work if your input file is perfect. Note that 16 is generally a ridiculously small length for a line buffer. Also only do your logic against your vector if (a) the file opens, and (b) passes the first test, which is an integral number of entries.